# how to convert date format using angular js without filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have date like sat Nov 15 2014
i want to convert this date in 15/11/2014 and i am using.

$filter('date')($scope.visa.rdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');

but it's not working.

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this question: [Format Date time in Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920892/format-date-time-in-angular-js)

Comment: are you ok to use moment.js??

Comment: `it's not working` is not a proper problem statement. What does happen and what errors are thrown (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

Convert `$scope.visa.rdate` (looks like it's a string) to `Date` object before you pass it into `$filter`:

```
$filter('date')(new Date($scope.visa.rdate), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Comment: What is `$scope.visa.rdate` exactly?

Comment: $scope.visa.rdate ia a viariable who holds the value of date which is in sat Nov 15 2014 format but i want to cahnge it in 15/11/2014.

Comment: $scope.visa.rdate = Sat Nov 15 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Comment: Works for me. What is the result for you?