# Time format in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use AngularJs. In a controller I get time. Then I want to show it in view with 2 `textview`. The first is `dd:mm:yy` the second is `hh:mm:ss` but when I use `{{transaction.transactionTime|date:'h:mm:ss a'}}` it return wrong result. How can I get time without date.

Comment: Please show us the code, and the output, and what you expect

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format Date time in Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920892/format-date-time-in-angular-js)

Comment: use moments.js and you can create you own filter for that if you need example for that please let me know. Hope this may help. LINK: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: what is your expected time-date format?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for this is actually pretty good on the angular site:

**HTML**

```
{{ date_expression | date : 'short'}}<br/>
{{ date_expression | date : 'fullDate'}}<br/>
{{ date_expression | date : 'longDate'}}<br/>
{{ date_expression | date : 'mediumDate'}}<br/>
{{ date_expression | date : 'shortDate'}}<br/>
{{ date_expression | date : 'mediumTime'}}<br/>
{{ date_expression | date : 'shortTime'}}<br/>
```

**Controller**

`$scope.date_expression = new Date();`

You can see the [Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eWOwiN8jn7fwNjOR7a1r?p=preview)

I believe `date:'h:mm:ss a'` would be what the documentation calls 'mediumTime'