# Formatting Date in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, my Angular code displays the date like this:

03/10/2016

```
 <span class="num">{{appointment.calendarSlot}}</span>
```

I want to display the date like this:

Friday, March 25

how can I do that?

UPDATE: The appointment.calendarSlot is a string and not Javascript Date

Comment: Duplicate question: [Format Date time in Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920892/format-date-time-in-angular-js)

Comment: @JohnDoe Updated my answer to format a string. Checkout my JSFiddle in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

```
 <span class="num">{{ appointment.calendarSlot | date:'EEEE, MMMM d' }}</span>
```

Comment: The appointment.calendarSlot is a string and not JS datetime object.

Comment: I think you might want to ask a separate question then, instead of confusing questions and answers here with a different question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

This line is for you:

```
'fullDate': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y' for en_US locale (e.g. Friday, September 3, 2010)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scope.date = new Date()  // controller


{{date | date:'EEEE, MMMM dd'}} // view
```

Comment: You don't need `dd`, just `d`

Comment: That depends) Maybe you need March 03 instead of March 3.

I looked at origin format 03/10/2016. It could be 3/10/2016 either. So i decided to put dd in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
    <span class="num" ng-bind="appointment.calendarSlot | date:'EEEE, MMMM d'"></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.appointment = {};
    $scope.appointment.calendarSlot = new Date('03/10/2016');
});
```

Working JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WfuAh/150/

Comment: This doesn't work if the string is in the format MM/dd/yy as stated in the OP's post.

Comment: I agree that should work, but I'm wondering if the OP left out a bunch of surrounding code. I suspect, although I have absolutely nothing to base this suspicion on, that the `<span>` referenced in the question is inside an `ng-repeat` construct.

Answer (score 1):

To make this the most flexible, I would add a custom filter to your app that converts the string to a date and then you can use the built in Angular date formatting filter.

```
.filter("asDate", function() {
    return function(input) {
        return Date.parse(input);
    }
})
```

Then your markup becomes:

```
<span class="num">{{ appointment.calendarSlot | asDate | date:'EEEE, MMMM d' }}</span>
```