# Convert 2017-09-12 00:00:00 into 2017-09-12 only using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I am retrieving date from database and i am getting date in this format  2017-09-12 00:00:00 but i want to get only Date in this format 2017-09-12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format Date time in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920892/format-date-time-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Use the date filter:

```
{{yourDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: just in case it is a string you will need to also do new **new Date('2017-09-12 00:00:00')** otherwise it wont apply the filter. Another suggestion is to use 'mediumDate' as that can be over written in the future for the entire app or create your own 'customMediumDate' constant so that it can be changed everywhere (and not a name reserved for angular defaults) once you use it.You can set the constant custom variable to 'yyyy-MM-dd' as well or just the string 'mediumDate'

Answer (score 0):

you can convert date in angularjs but you can filter date or format date using moment 
`moment(yourdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`;

else you can use filter in html as

```
{{ date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```