# How to Convert Date to a Timestamp string angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, timestamp, date-formatting

How do I convert a Date to a timestamp string?

my variable is:

```
d: Date = new Date();
```

how do I get a timestamp of that variable?

I'm using Angular2. Pleas help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: What format should the timestamp be in? Possible duplicate of [*Format Date time in AngularJS*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920892/format-date-time-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This more a javascript question than angular/typescript, but you can get a timestamp using

```
Date.now(); // return timestamp
```

You can read more here: [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)
or an Angular pipe:

```
{{valueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
d: string = new Date().toLocaleString();
```

Or `toISOString()`

But you can find best solutions here

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString